# How to get access token in Gowalla Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0

I am struggling with how to use OAuth2 and Check-in with [Gowalla-Java](http://code.google.com/p/gowalla-java/wiki/OAuth2Example).

I don't understand how to Request Authorization, the callback code, or how to get an access token, and would like a quick overview.

Answer (score 1):

all the code needed for the library is in the webpage you're linking.

I'll explain step by step:

- Request Authorization (WebView)

The last string is a web url you need to redirect the user to (in a webview).
This gowalla webpage will ask the user an authorization for your app.
The webpage after the authorization will have a special parameter "code" string in the url. You will need to parse it for the next step.

- Request Access (Token)

To use oauth you need to request a token (special string) using the previous code.
Keep it as long as you can because it will be needed each time you post.
Eventually the token will expire and you will need to ask for another one.

- Check In

Follow the code and you will checkin.

Comment: Murphy can you post some line code to generate ACCESS TOKEN in android

Comment: OAuth oauth = new OAuth(API_KEY, SECRET_KEY, CALLBACK);
OAuthAccessTokenResponse token = oauth.requestAccessToken(Scope.READ_WRITE, code);
String token = token.getAccessToken();

Comment: i search for alternative,thanx for you support